# HTML Scroll position when anchor clicked

Tags: jquery, html

I have a MVC app and using JQuery.

I have anchor that I setup like this

```
<a href="#" id="addcomment">Add Comment</a>
```

then when the anchor is clicked I do this

```
$('#addcomment').click(function() {
    $('#divComments').slideDown(2000);
});
```

Problem is when the anchor is clicked
the browser scrolls to top of window
immediately the link is clicked and
then the div scrolls

How do I stop that happening??

Malcolm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add `return false;` at the bottom of your click function to prevent the default link event action from happening. The default link event in this case would be going to the top of the page because the href of `#` tells the browser to go to the top. So it would look like this:

```
$('#addcomment').click(function() {
    $('#divComments').slideDown(2000);
    return false;
});
```

While this is acceptable too:

```
$('#addcomment').click(function(e) {
    $('#divComments').slideDown(2000);
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

[Documentation here](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/jQuery.Event#event.preventDefault.28.29).

Answer (score 3):

What's wrong with using a named anchor?

No need for the overhead of javascript.

Comment: I agree.  Why not just the tag and have to maintain extra script?